# How to return a promise from JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

Imagine I have `X`, `Y` and `Z` functions, all returning promises and ready to chain. What I want to do is to notify about the progress after they are complete and handle error. What is better to write and why (what are the consequences):

A.

```
function my_func(index, size){
    return X
        .then(Y)
        .then(Z)
        .then(
           function(data){
               var dfd = new $.Deferred();
               dfd.notify("progress", index / size, 'OK');
               dfd.resolve(data);
               return dfd.promise();
           },
           function(){
               return handleError(arguments, size, index);
           }
        );
}
```

or

B.

```
function my_func(index, size){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    X
    .then(Y)
    .then(Z)
    .then(
        function(data){
            dfd.notify("progress", index / size, 'OK');
            dfd.resolve(data);
        },
        function(){
            return handleError(arguments, size, index);
        }
    )
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

Also, what is the difference between:

```
X.then(Y).then(Z);
```

and:

```
$.when(X).then(Y).than(Z);
```

If `$.when` part is unnecessary, why doeas it exist in jQuery at all?

Comment: comment removed as from @Benjamin Gruenbaum comment.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter is unnecessary. It's just extra cruft. `$.when` is useful for converting values to promises and for aggregation.

Here is an average `$.when` use case:

```
$.when($.get(...),$.get(...)).then(function(firstResult,secondResult){
     // access both results here
});
```

You can use both results here, both have finished.

As for the first question - basically B. The first option is the [deferred anti pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-anti-pattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) and is better avoided. See the [link to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-anti-pattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) question on why.

Comment: Thank for this explanation, what about the first part of my question?

Comment: Agreeing with @BenjaminGruenbaum here, the 2nd approach seems way cleaner, as the `my_func` function properly wraps what is happening inside. But... all in all, I think you are under the wrong assumption that the `.then()` chaining will make things happen in that order, that only if `Y` is resolved, that then `Z` will happen. This is not the case, all the `.then()`s in both cases happen when `X` resolves. I too was under that impression, but see this JSFiddle (press the 2nd button): http://jsfiddle.net/vH84q/1/ (EDIT: Have the browser console open to see what's happening.)

Answer (score 0):

The main difference would be that you are relying on `X` to be an object that has the method `then`.
Passing a non Deferred/promise object to `$.when` will treat it as a resolved `Deferred`, which personally I would prefer as it makes the coupling between the functions more loose.

Comment: A more correct term might be "fulfilled", it will treat it as a fulfilled deferred.

Comment: I agree, but I actually quoted from the jQuery API documentation ;) "...it will be treated as a resolved Deferred...", see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: The same comment goes here - I appreciate explanation of usage of `when` but to me the first part of my question is more important :)